# Excel source has String to date conversion into oracle

Tags: java, excel, date, oracle11g, pentaho

In Excel sheet I have a string `Oct 20 2015 5:30 PM` I want to convert this into date format `yyyy/mm/dd` in Penatho DI and want to load into Oracle.

I have tried with below Javascript:

```
var x = EFF_DATE; EFF_DATE is stream having "Oct 20 2015 5:30 PM"

var da = new Date(x);
```

But this is not working. If I give Hard code string it works like `var da = new Date('Oct 20 2015 5:30 PM');`
Here my varaiable `EFF_DATE` is not worked in function.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Select values` step to convert a string to date in Pentaho DI.

Here is a setup that works for your example:

[image: Select values step]

Here is the date string: `MMM dd yyyy h:mm a`